# React components styling methods

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this following component -

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Error from './Error'

class NavigationBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="nav">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to={"/data"} className="nav-link"> Data </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to={"/analysis"} className="nav-link"> Analysis </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to={"/Monitor"} className="nav-link"> Monitor </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <Route path={"/webiks/:user"} component={Error}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

In addition i added a nav.css file to  index.html in order to make some changes to the boostrap styling.

The problem is that when entering the "webkis/:user" url the style only boostrap styling without the changes of the nav.css file.
If one can explaing the reason , and also to mention some of the common methods
for styling components (which is NOT an inline styling).

Thanks.

Comment: In case you have URLS in your css - make sure they are all absolute (and not relative). images/fonts should start with `/` (and not just the name of the file).

Answer (score 0):

Place nav.css in the same folder as NavigationBar.js, then add this line on your import list: `import './nav.css'`